# /etc/crypttab for anyusb?

Tags: debian, encryption, luks, crypttab

On my LUKS-encrypted machine, I have edited my `/etc/crypttab` to inform the system that a keyfile is on a pendrive. I did this by *adding* a line in `/etc/crypttab`, using the UUID of my encrypted HDD, and also the UUID of my pendrive.

But I plan to make *N* such pendrives. I cannot get the UUID list of them all.

My question is: how can I ensure that my machine will look for keyfile in any usb pendrive plugged-in ?

**EDIT** I guess I should not specify the UUID in `/etc/crypttab` but /dev/sdXX ?

Comment: Are those USB copies of an original USB? if they are you can use the same UUID. Just `dd` from the original and all will have the same UUID.